# How to annotate a django queryset with a function of prefetched subquery

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

I would like to have a field `status` on a queryset that is derived from a function of a prefetched set of feedback values.

Example of feedback:

```
feedback = [
    {'action': 0, 'user': 1},
    {'action': 1, 'user': 13},
]
```

If I were writing this on a Serializer I would do this:

```
    def get_status(self, obj):
        # Squash all feedback into single status value
        fb = obj.feedback.all()
        vals = [f.action for f in fb]
        if len(vals) == 0:
            return 0  # Unconfirmed
        if sum(vals) == 0:
            return 1 # Confirmed
        return 2  # Rejected
```

However I'd like to move this logic down into my view's queryset to enable ordering on the field.

```
queryset = Foo.objects\
        .prefetch_related('feedback')\
        .annotate(status="???")
```

I'd like to know what set of available query expressions could mimic the logic of the python function `get_status` above.

Comment: You can not call a function in a an `.annotate(..)` since the database layer does not know about functions. You can try to convert the above to a expression. You by the way do *not* need `.prefetch_related(..)` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not call a function in a an `.annotate(..)` since the database layer does not know about functions. You can try to convert the above to an expression. You do *not* need `.prefetch_related(..)` for that. Here you can make use of [**`Case`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) and [**`When`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case):

```
from django.db.models import Case, Count, IntegerField, Sum, Value, When

queryset = Foo.objects.annotate(
    nfeedback=Count('feedback'),
    sumfeedback=Sum('feedback__action')
).annotate(
    status=Case(
       When(nfeedback=0, then=Value(0)),
       When(sumfeedback=0, then=Value(1)),
       default=Value(2),
       output_field=IntegerField()
    )
)
```

Comment: This solved my issue. (Your accurate and speedy answer is much appreciated) For clarity, if I *don't* use prefetch_related(), will this not incur DB hits on a per row basis?

Comment: @IanDanforth: not for the annotation, since then Django will make a JOIN. The `.select_related(..)` and `.prefetch_related(..)` should be used when *fetching* related model data *to the Python/Django layer*. But this will make a JOIN and aggregates in the database, so it will result in *one* query.